# Unity 3D importing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used to code in c# using Xna then I saw Unity 3D engine and I downloaded latest version installed correctly started development of my game but suddenly when I was importing my animated character Unity 3d blocked my pc ! I noticed that my keyboard goes off when that happened and I cant move arrow or call task menager I can only restart pc ! So brother and sisters help me on my way .

Comment: Does this always happen when you try to import it? Has the model been used in other things before without error?

Comment: Always . I used it in Xna it worked but I decided to download Unity and this problem occured .

Comment: What kind of model is it?

Comment: I exported model as fbx for Unity

Answer (score 0):

Model files that are placed in the Assets folder in your Unity project are automatically imported and stored as Unity assets.

A model file may contain a 3D model, such as a character, a building, or a piece of furniture. The model is imported as multiple assets. In the Project view the main imported object is a Model Prefab. Usually there are also up to several Mesh objects that are referenced by the Model Prefab.

A model file may also contain animation data which can be used to animate this model or other models. The animation data is imported as one or more Animation Clips.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand in your question is that whenever you try to import `assets` into `unity` it makes trouble. 
Try to place them in the folder in your drive and then run the project in Unity.
The normal path of Unity project is `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand; Your computer is spazzing out when you're trying to import Animated 3D characters into Unity 3D

I have faced a similar problem.

The solution I believe might work is :

1. Create the appropriate folders inside of unity. Assets > Models
2. Outside of unity, place the OBJ file for the models into your c:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\Your Project or wherever it might be, in the Assets\Models folder.
3. Then when you're inside unity, it should be in there without any issues.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, It worked for me. 

You just have to make sure that the directories are made properly.